# Remove Key:Value property from YAML File using Java

Tags: java, generics, yaml, linkedhashmap

**Goal**: I have a YAML file that needed to remove some key: value properties from. Then I want to create a new YAML file with doesn't exist removed key: value properties. The required key should be removed from the whole YAML file.

**Expected Result**: Should Iterate through the YAML File and identify the required key: value to be removed and then remove and continue searching for such key: value properties.

**Actual Result**: Even though iterating through the YAML file desired key: value property won't' remove from the YAML File.

**Errors**: No Compile or Runtime errors, there seems to be a logical error.

**What I have tried**:

- Use Jackson ObjectMapper to read the YAML file.
- Put all the properties into LinkedHashMap such that I can preserve the order and I can remove items

**My Logic**: Implement two methods

- one is to iterate the LinkedHashMap and ArrayList object
- another one it to check whether a specific key is removable
- If a removable key is found and remove from the LinkedHashMap and continues searching the same key in other items in the YAML file.

> for example I want to remove `"originalRef": "Conditions"` (the key is String data type) from the YAML file. This key can contain in a LinkedHashMap. Also, There could be ArrayLists which contains multiple LinkedHashMaps.

**Code**: Below are the YAML file I'm using for these purpose.
*api-test.yml*
this only contains a small portion of my big YAML file.

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: |-
    Planner application is a proposal system enables user to create, manage plan .  
    It also enables network user to publish plan 
  version: '1.0'
  title: Planner API
  contact:
    name: API team
    email: apiteam@test.com
  license:
    name: Copyright © 2020 test
host: aos-dev.test.com
basePath: /unifiedplanner
tags:
  - name: Additional Fee APIs
    description: Additional Fee Controller
  - name: Condition APIs
    description: Condition Controller
  - name: Conditions Status APIs
paths:
  '/v1/{apiKey}/entity/{entityId}':
    post:
      tags:
        - Condition APIs
      summary: Save New Conditions Entity
      operationId: saveNewConditions
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: Authorization
          in: header
          description: Authorization
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: apiKey
          in: path
          description: API Key
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: conditions
          description: Conditions Entity that needs to be saved
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Conditions'
            originalRef: Conditions
        - name: entityId
          in: path
          description: Entity ID
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Conditions'
            originalRef: Conditions
      deprecated: false
    put:
      tags:
        - Condition APIs
      summary: Modify / Overwrite existing Conditions Entity
      operationId: modifyConditions
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: Authorization
          in: header
          description: Authorization
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: apiKey
          in: path
          description: API Key
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: conditions
          description: Conditions Entity that needs to be updated
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Conditions'
            originalRef: Conditions
        - name: entityId
          in: path
          description: Entity ID
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Conditions'
            originalRef: Conditions
      deprecated: false
```

---

below is the Java class for parsing above the YAML file and doing the needful.

```
package com.aos.tools.aostool.yaml;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

@Service
public class YamlProcessorGeneric {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YamlProcessorGeneric.class);

    public YamlProcessorGeneric() throws IOException {
        process();
    }

    public void process() throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

        final Map<String, Object> api = objectMapper.readValue(new File("api-test.yaml"),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });

        final Map<String, Object> path = (Map<String, Object>) api.get("paths");
        extractLinkedHashMap(path);

        // write YAML file
        final Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        objectMapper.writeValue(new File(date.toString() + "api-updated.yaml"), api);
    }

    private void extractLinkedHashMap(final Map<String,Object> itemMap) {
        itemMap.entrySet().forEach(k -> {

            // if k is a linkedhashmap and again iterate through
            if(k.getValue() instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
                extractLinkedHashMap((Map<String, Object>) k.getValue());
            }

            // if k is an arraylist then iterate through to till I find a linkedhashmap
            // so that I can remove an item.
            if(k.getValue() instanceof ArrayList) {
                ((ArrayList<?>) k.getValue()).forEach(singleItem -> {
                   if(!(singleItem instanceof String)) {
                       extractLinkedHashMap((Map<String, Object>) singleItem);
                   }
                });
            }

            // check for a specific key , if found remove from the linkedhashmap
            // but this doesn't work
            if(isRemovable(k.getKey())) {
                itemMap.remove(k);
            }

        });
    }

    private boolean isRemovable(final String key) {
        // eg:- I want to remove key with originalRef
        String removableString = "originalRef";
        return key.equals(removableString);
    }
}
```

---

for the demonstration process I will attach a screenshot when I was debugging the application.
All the values of `itemMap` .

[image]

I'm currently out of options trying out. Please Can anyone give me direction where I'm doing wrong here.
Any help would be very much appreciated.
Good day!

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant or somebody want to know, how to do.

First, lets say we have Yaml object:

```
public class Project  {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private long lastUpdate;

    public Project() {
    }

    // getter, setter
}
```

now we want to remove `lastUpdate` field from data.

1. Remove getter from `Project` (update UI to not use getter of property)
2. Start project
3. Save the Yaml object again -> `lastUpdate` property from file is gone
4. Now you can remove `lastUpdate` and setter from `Project`

If the project is already in use by many people:

1. Remove getter from `Project` and clean UI
2. After some time in use can remove the property from file (if all users have ones saved new Yaml object)